# Does anyone knows if i can fix this boolean behaivour when i join meshes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting

I did a hand as a separate mesh of the body. but when i used boolean modifier to unite them, they still behaive as separated meshes, idk how to ask this i am very new at blender.

[image]

Comment: Please use a descriptive title that summarizes the content of the question

Comment: Sorry i am very new in this area and i don´t know how to ask properly.

Comment: That will do fine